# Calling a web method on WCF service using Func delegate

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to consume a WCF service and I have written a separate interface for the same

```
public interface IWebServiceInvoker 
{ 
T Invoke<T>(Func<IServiceContract, T> operation); 
}
```

Now while consuming the web service I will call something like this:

```
var data = invoker.Invoke(svc => svc.GetData);
```

I am not able to get an implementation for the IWebServiceInvoker i.e How I would be able to call the particular web method using the Func delegate. In the implementation I have created the Client something like this
    public T Invoke(Func operation)
        {

```
        try
        {
            using (var serviceClient = new ServiceContractClient(binding, address))
            {


                ----------------//not sure of the invocation of particular method
            }


        }
```

Comment: FYI, your terminology is off - WCF services don't use the term "web method". That term is used by the legacy ASMX web services.

Comment: my apologies, I need to consume the operation for a particular WCF service using Func delegate

Comment: I think I need to create a Channel Factory and then invoke the operation on the channel created.